# How to build a mirror vdev which is bootable via UEFI?

Tags: boot, uefi, zfs

I have a server with two identical disks. I would like to create a ZFS mirror vdev from these disks, create a ZFS filesystem on it, use it as the root filesystem and boot from it.

I have done this successfully in the past with the legacy boot mechanism. However, this time, I'd like to boot via EFI. Therefore, I have created the following partition layout on each of the disks:

```
Device          Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     1048576 4000780287 3999731712  1.9T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sda2          40    1048575    1048536  512M EFI System
/dev/sda9  4000780288 4000797326      17039  8.3M Solaris reserved 1
```

Please note that `/dev/sda2` is the partition which contains the EFI bootloader. It is formatted as `FAT32`.

The second disk is `/dev/sdb` with identical partition layout.

When I try to create the mirror vdev via

```
zpool create -o ... -O ... rpool mirror /dev/disk/by-id/ata-disk1 /dev/disk/by-id/ata-disk2
```

I get the following error message:

```
invalid vdev specification
use '-f' to override the following errors:
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-disk1 contains a filesystem of type 'vfat'
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-disk2 contains a filesystem of type 'vfat'
```

Of course, I have researched how to solve that problem for quite a long time, but to no avail. There are two common solutions to it which I both can't apply:

1. Remove the FAT partition or format it with a different file system type. In my case, this does not make sense because this is the EFI system partition which *must* exist and *must* be formatted with one of the FAT variants; otherwise, I can't put an EFI bootloader onto the disk, or the UEFI BIOS won't find the bootloader.
2. Use `zpool create -f ...`, i.e. add `-f` to the command shown above. This does not make sense either, because it will make `zpool` destroy that partition, leading to the same problem.

Another idea I had myself was to first create the partition layout without partition 2, but leaving enough space for it, then create the mirror vdev, and then add partition 2 afterwards. I am quite sure that this would work, but I have also read that this will lead to all sorts of problems, for example when replacing one of the disks and trying to resilver. Basically, it boils down to that ZFS does not like such partitions on its disks, and if I manage to work around that problem when initially creating the vdev, then I'll pay for it later, probably not being able to do rescue operations or to replace defective disks.

So what would be the correct way to put an EFI system partition onto a disk which I want to use as part of a mirror vdev?

Comment: I've always used ZFS on partitions (creating a small one for boot and the rest for ZFS), and never experienced nor even heard of any such problems when using partitions -- a block device of size X works like any other block device of size X. (Except for alleged changes in performance.) I would even guess a partition can be safer when replacing a disk with one that's smaller by a few MB (that happens).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have no clue why I didn't try that. Probably all examples I saw were using the whole disk ... In the meanwhile, I have tried it, and it worked. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.